# Java Web Start JFrame size not respected

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

I'm creating a new JFrame from inside a Java Web Start application. The content of the frame often changes and it wasn't resizing, so I overrode revalidate to explicitly set the frame size. When I run the application in my IDE (Idea), the size of the frame is what I expect based on the preferredSize and minimumSize. When I bundle the application into a WebStart app, deploy it, and run it through javaws, the window is much much larger than I expect.

I've created the test case below:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {

  JFrame sampleFrame = new JFrame() {
    public void revalidate() {
      super.revalidate();
      pack();
      _log.severe( "BEFORE: Preferred Size = " + getPreferredSize() + " - Minimum Size = " + getMinimumSize() + " - Size = " + getSize() );
      setSize( getPreferredSize() );
      _log.severe( "AFTER: Preferred Size = " + getPreferredSize() + " - Minimum Size = " + getMinimumSize() + " - Size = " + getSize() );
    }
  };

  sampleFrame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 100, 100 ) );
  sampleFrame.pack();
  sampleFrame.setVisible( true );
  sampleFrame.revalidate();
}
```

When I run the test through WebStart, the console indicates:

SEVERE: BEFORE: Preferred Size = java.awt.Dimension[width=110,height=130] - Minimum Size = java.awt.Dimension[width=10,height=30] - Size = java.awt.Dimension[width=110,height=130]
SEVERE: AFTER: Preferred Size = java.awt.Dimension[width=110,height=130] - Minimum Size = java.awt.Dimension[width=10,height=30] - Size = java.awt.Dimension[width=110,height=130]

Even though the log says that the JFrame size is 110x130, it is actually around 1300x930! Any ideas why that might be?

I'm running Debian 6.0.7 ("squeeze") and Java(TM) Web Start 10.45.2.18-fcs with (Java build 1.7.0_45-b18)

Comment: This isn't the roblem, but did you mean `sampleFrame. revalidate();` or `sampleFrame.revalidate();`?

Comment: `Don't override revalidate()`. There is no reason to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JFrame.setBounds() instead of setSize() -- it's what I've always used to resize JFrames, though I cannot tell from the javadocs just what the difference is between the two.

Comment: setBounds has no effect either. Another interesting thing is that I can't resize the frame by dragging its corners, even though I haven't setResizable(false). It's like there's something in Java or the OS that is preventing the window size from changing, even though internally it recognizes the preferredSize and size.

Comment: Both methods' javadoc indicate that the native OS might ignore the call, but I haven't run across it.  What system is it?

Comment: I believe you're correct. I just tested on Windows and Mac and the problem doesn't exist on those platforms. My specs are above in the original post. Maybe it is something specific to Debian or KDE. Leaving the question open for now, in case someone has a definitive answer; I'd like to find a workaround for all clients.

Comment: setSize() simply invokes setBounds() with the current x/y values of the frame, so there should be no difference between the two methods from a sizing point of view. setSize() is just a convenience method.

Comment: Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Comment: Nobody seems to know a workaround for Linux/KDE, so giving the answer to rcook, who identified that it might be OS-specific.

Comment: I appreciate the thought, though also admit the possibility of questions that don't get answered...

Answer (score 1):

> The content of the frame often changes and it wasn't resizing,

Call [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) which:

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. ..

Comment: Why would this vary based on whether you are running with JWS or not?

Comment: @ryvantage  To be honest, I missed that part.  But then, with setting preferred sizes and other very questionable practices in that snippet, the OP is probably better off posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for your tip, but calling pack() IS the obvious thing I had first tried. It doesn't work on Debian Linux under KDE, which is why I submitted this question.